# What does this Perl mean, and how would one translate it into Java?

Tags: java, perl

I found this in some code I am having to translate into java, and I am lost in translating it. Does anyone know what this transliteration is doing, and if there is any java equivalent this transliteration?

```
$zone_filename=~tr^/^\\^;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `$zone_filename` doesn't contain a string, the value is first stringified. Then, the string in `$zone_filename` is replaced with one where all instances of `/` are replaced with `\`.

If you have further problems coding this in Java, please show your work and identify what problems you are having.

Comment: So with your helpful information would the following be the literal translation?       zone_filename = zone_filename.toString().replaceAll("/", "\");

Comment: `zone_filename` is probably already a string, so you can drop the `.toString` `.replaceAll("/", "\")` does indeed to the trick (though I think you need to escape that `\ ` for it to compile...)

Comment: You were right again. Thank you for catching that, and thank you for your assistance.